# Casting a Python Tkinter IntVar() list as a regular int list?

Tags: python, tkinter

Using the Tkinter get() function I can get the IntVar() values in some Tkinter checkboxes:

```
wind_solar = IntVar()
wind_CC = IntVar()
wind_CT = IntVar()
renewables = [wind_solar.get(), wind_CC.get(), wind_CT.get()]
print("renewable resources to simulate:", '\n', renewables)
```

The printed output is [1, 0, 1], which is technically correct, but it's printing as an IntVar list whereas I want to print it as an integer list (i.e. a non-Tkinter list). I.e. I just want to convert an IntVar list to a regular list. Help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying? This will give `SyntaxError` or `NameError`. Since you are using `get()` the list will be full of integers, not `IntVar`.

Comment: If you want a list of integers, why are you casting the values to `IntVar`?

Comment: Better to also include your `checkboxes`.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to convert an IntVar list to a regular list. Help?

If that is the case, don't cast the values to `IntVar`s

```
window_solar = IntVar()
wind_CC = IntVar()
wind_CT = IntVar()
...
renewables = [wind_solar.get(), wind_CC.get(), wind_CT.get()]
print("renewable resources to simulate:", '\n', renewables)
```

Or, if you already have a list of `IntVar`s, you can use a list comprehension:

```
vars = [window_solar, wind_CC, wind_CT]
...
renewables = [var.get() for var in vars]
print("renewable resources to simulate:", '\n', renewables)
```

Comment: Hey, so these are IntVars for a set of checkboxes. It seems to break my user interface when I don't use IntVars. I like your solution but it doesn't seem to be working with that sadly...

Comment: Those variables still can be `IntVars`. I'm just saying that `renewables` doesn't need to be a list of `IntVar`s.